Lucas sequence $V_n(4,2)$ and testing primality of Wagstaff numbers
It is known that $V_{2^{p-2}}(4,1) \equiv 0 \pmod{2^p-1}$ iff $2^p-1$ is prime number, where $V_n(P,Q)$ denotes Lucas sequence and $p$ denotes prime number. I noticed  the following congruence holds $$V_{2^{p-1}}(4,2) \equiv 8 \pmod{\dfrac{2^p+1}{3}}$$    whenever $p>3$ is prime and $\dfrac{2^p+1}{3}$ is prime. Here you can find exponents of Wagstaff primes and here is PARI/GP implementation of test.
Can someone explain what is going on here? Why this congruence holds true for Wagstaff primes?
EDIT
It seems that following congruence also holds true
$$V_{2^{p-1}}(4,2) \equiv 4 \pmod{2^p-1}$$ whenever $p>3$ is prime and $2^p-1$ is prime.

This answer is not quite complete as it only shows $V_{2^{p-1}}(4,2)\equiv \pm8\mod\frac{2^p+1}3$. The same method works for the second congruence as well, but again only up to sign. Perhaps someone can fill this gap.
To simplify notation, let $n=2^{p-1}, q=\frac{2^p+1}3$, so $n=\frac{3q-1}2$. Let $x=2+\sqrt 2,y=2-\sqrt 2$. The closed form for the Lucas sequence is $V_n(P,Q) = x^n+y^n$. We work in the ring of integers of $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ modulo $q$. Note $q\equiv5\mod8$, so $\big(\frac2q\big)=-1$ and $q$ is inert in $K$. Therefore $x^q\equiv y\mod q$ (can see this via binomial theorem, or conceptually since $q$ is inert the Galois automorphism $x\mapsto y$ is the Frobenius over $q$). Now we have $x^n=x^{\frac{3q-1}2}=x^qx^{\frac{q-1}2}\equiv yx^{\frac{q-1}2}\mod q$. Next note that $2=xy \equiv x^{q+1}$, so $(x^{(q-1)/2})^2\equiv2/x^2=3-2\sqrt 2\mod q$. We also have $(1-\sqrt2)^2=3-2\sqrt 2$. Therefore $x^{(q-1)/2} \equiv \pm(1-\sqrt2)\mod q$. Hence we get $$x^n\equiv yx^{(q-1)/2}\equiv\pm(2-\sqrt2)(1-\sqrt 2)=\pm(4-3\sqrt 2).$$
Then $V_n(P,Q)=x^n+y^n=\operatorname{Tr}(x^n)\equiv\pm 8\mod q$.
If we apply similar ideas to $q=2^p-1$ (if this is prime), then we get $V_n(P,Q)\equiv\pm4\mod q$ and the sign is given by the Legendre symbol $\big(\frac{2+2^{(p+1)/2}}q\big)$.
